# Matching first end bracket in perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following regex:

```
perl -pi -w -e "s/(\bgetnitemc)\(([^,]+),([^,]+)\)/\$1\(\$2,\$3,1,1,''\)/g;" d_*.sas
```

Which has the following impact (git diff):

```
-               if getnitemc(l_sub2,'OBJTYPE') = 'SLIST' then
-                  l_tempa = insertc(l_tempa,getnitemc(l_sub2,'OBJNAME'));
+               if getnitemc(l_sub2,'OBJTYPE',1,1,'') = 'SLIST' then
+                  l_tempa = insertc(l_tempa,getnitemc(l_sub2,'OBJNAME'),1,1,'');
```

So the behaviour for the first line is working as desired.  However, in the second line, the part I'm trying to add (`,1,1,''`) is applied to the wrapper function (`insertc`) rather than the target function (`getnitemc`).  It kind of 'skips a bracket' if you can see what I mean.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!  so I think the negation operator (`^`) was including the end bracket in the capture..

Solution:

```
perl -pi -w -e "s/(\bgetnitemc)\(([^,]+),([^,)]+)\)/\$1\(\$2,\$3,1,1,''\)/g;" d_*.sas
```

(`[^,)]`)

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is to exclude `)` from `getnitemc`'s argument list. All you need to match the existing arguments is `[^)]*`.

After some cleanup, you get

```
perl -i -wpe's/\b(getnitemc\([^)]*)/$1,1,1,\x27\x27/g' d_*.sas
```

or

```
perl -i -wpe's/\bgetnitemc\([^)]*\K/,1,1,\x27\x27/g' d_*.sas   # 5.10+
```